# Creating a daily report for USPS

Tags: shipping, reports, ups

I have Udropship through Magento. 
How do I create a daily manifest or shipped items report for the day. The USPS is asking me if I can provide this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get this report, but it depends on what format/type does USPS want? As far as I know, they are interested in some type of JSON or XML data.

1. Create a custom report in Magento
2. Use your MySQL skills to pull data directly from database
3. Use Tableau (if you have a license) to create repots easily
4. Search for a Magento extension that would do the job for you

If you want to send the report automatically, you can set up cron jobs, or use an automation service like Zapier.